# capacitor community/http handle errors

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I often use Axios to perform requests in my applications, however due to incompatibility with iphone, I had to use the capacitor-community/http library, however the try catch blocks are always returning success, even if there was an error in the request. How can I handle errors using this library?

```
try {
        await Requester.auth.public.login(formData);
       
          this.$store.dispatch('login', user);
          this.$root.$emit('showToast', {
            text: 'Seja bem vindo!',
            color: 'success',
          });
          this.$router.push({ name: 'Cotacao' });
   
      } catch (err) {
        this.$root.$emit('showToast', {
          text: err.response?.data ?? err.toString(),
          color: 'error',
        });
      } finally {
        this.loading.submitForm = false;
      }
    },
```

My request

```
const login = async (formData: AuthLoginFormData): Promise<User> => {
  const res: HttpResponse = await Http.post({
    url: `${BASE_URL}public/auth/login`,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    data: formData,
    webFetchExtra: {
      credentials: 'include',
    },
  });

  return res.data;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Install Latest https://github.com/capacitor-community/http plugin

use function

```
public async login(formData: AuthLoginFormData){
  let options = {
      url: `${BASE_URL}public/auth/login`,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      data: formData,
      webFetchExtra: {
        credentials: 'include',
      }
  };
  let response: HttpResponse = await Http.request(options);
  if (response.status === 200) {
    return Promise.resolve(res);
  } 
    return Promise.reject(response.data);
 }
```